# Javascript : access link beside tr event

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

I added events on the "tr"s of a table :

```
$("table#mytable tr").on("click", function() {
    // doing stuff
});
```

But still I have links inside some td cells : is it possible and how to access those links and follow them when clicked (accessing new page as they should behave), but keeping the other general behaviour of the "tr"s when I click everywhere else ?

Thanks

: with Django 2.0, JQuery 3.3.1

Comment: Change selector to `"#mytable a"` to select `a`s?

Comment: ok.. now I feel stupid ^^ well more than usual.. Thanks ! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the clicked element using `e.target` in your event.

Pseudocode:

```
$("table#mytable tr").on("click", function(e) {
  // if e.target == "<a href=''>" element, Then "return;"
  // else -> do other stuff
});
```